# Why does this query slowdown in MongoDB using pymongo?

Tags: performance, mongodb, networking, pymongo

I am running a similar query 374 times and up to the 367th time performance is reasonable but then the time to return results deteriorates dramatically.

The collection I query stores posts where each post has a unique ID and there will be several versions of the same post in the database. The task is to get the last version of each post ID. The approach is to get a distinct list of post IDs and then for each post ID get the post ID with the highest ObjectID.

This could also be done through the aggregation framework but it errors with `exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)`

This is the code:

```
for oi in obj_ids: #obj_ids is a list of strings containing unique post IDs
    t1 = time.time()
    o = col.find({'object_id':oi}).sort('_id', -1).limit(1)[0]
    t2 = time.time()
```

The `col.find` function is timed and here is how this query's performance deteriorates over time:

```
364 of 374 in 0.00369000434875s
365 of 374 in 0.0037579536438s
366 of 374 in 0.00375485420227s
367 of 374 in 0.00367307662964s
368 of 374 in 0.735110998154s
369 of 374 in 3.09494900703s
370 of 374 in 5.16561698914s
371 of 374 in 7.14517307281s
372 of 374 in 8.3472340107s
373 of 374 in 8.61702394485s
374 of 374 in 8.07462406158s
```

Any ideas what is happening?

UPDATE 2012/11/01

Using the Python cprofile I found that there seems to be a network bottleneck

[image: sorted by time]

EDIT:
spelling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to indices. I created a compound index on _id and object_id, when actually  I should have added a separate _id index and object_id index. After doing this the ~380 queries run in about 10s as opposed to 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you might be running out of RAM. On linux you can check your RAM by `$ free -m`

See whether you have free RAM or not. The factor by which it spikes up latency seems like you are hitting disk (swap operation).

In case python is being a memory hog, use [gc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html) module.

Comment: You are right that it is swapping. However, why is that if they are independent queries why is mongo not clearing it's cache?

Comment: Well, mongo loves RAM. It caches pages in use. But I think problem is not that of mongo, but perhaps of Python. Reason being, while you are in iteration, the cursor objects live in memory. Instead have a function call within loop which handles cursors.

Comment: I did what you suggested but the application still slows down in exactly the same way. Profiling the script shows that most of the time is spent in `_socket.socket.recv` (see screenshot attached) So it seems that the bottle neck is the network.

Comment: Are you instantiating a new connection in every iteration? Verify that.

Comment: I tried both instantiating a new connection in each iteration and keep a connection alive. The result is the same.

Comment: Actually what I meant was, the reason why you might be having performance loss could be because you have new connection in each iteration. Avoid instantiating new connections in every iteration. Instead prefer having finite alive connections. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22585/discussion-between-davida-and-sushant-gupta)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the aggregation framework, and having the "aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)" error, you can use the $out statement, to place the results in a temporary collection, and then go over the results from that collection. This can be faster if you have a large number of elements in your collection, as you end up with less queries and thus less network latency.